# How to run "file upload" test case in Hudson 3.2.1

Tags: java, maven, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium webdriver test cases through Hudson 3.2.1 
But in "file upload" test case I'm using Robot Framework which is why it is not getting executed in Hudson. It running perfectly fine through maven separately. Below is my code for File upload:

```
public static void setClipboardData(String string) {
       StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}


driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='photo']")).click();    

setClipboardData("C:\\Users\\Townscript\\Downloads\\kick.jpg");

  Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(5000);
        }
        catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why you want to do this in `Robot`, selenium can do file uploads ( not in Safari though)

Comment: Other than Robot, I could only use AutoIT for file upload in selenium. I did not find any other alternative for the same.

Comment: What browser your using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the HTML tag input has `type = file` i.e

```
<input type="file">
```

you can directly upload the file using sendkeys.

```
WebDriver driver;
driver.findElement(By.<yourlocator>).sendKeys("FilePath");
```

hope it helps!

Comment: There is no textarea on the webpage for providing the filepath. On the click of "Browse" button, it opens machine window for which you cannot get the xpath to give sendKeys.

Comment: @Minaz: Ya, I was asking for this only, because Selenium can do that.